# create a collapsing toobar layout with half of image in collapsing toolbar and nested scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image]

```
I wanted to create a layout as shown in picture, with following contents as follows,
  a)Toolbar
  b)Collapsing toolbar
  c)container with many edittext and button with nested scrollview
```

I am not able to create this layout with collapsing toolbar as how to place the image between 2 and 3 with both area having separate background.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see _CoordinateLayout_ in xml.  Use _CoordinateLayout_.

Comment: @i hadn't used them, as i cleared it in my question that i am unable to do so and don't want my code to be followed, as i just posted my code, so that others can know i don't want this type of solution.